# countif changes with filtered columns vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on VBA program, the program is suppose to count the number of cells within two columns that meet a particular criteria and it will display the value in cell A5. As the range has been autofiltered. When I filter the range for example only show the number of orders that are "L" and "Veg" in Y1. Range A5 should change.

While the program is able to count the number items that meet the two criteria it does not recalculate when i filter the result.

For example lets say in total there 5 Large Veg for whole school.  If I filter the result to only show Year 1, the result still remain 5 when there is only one order.

```
Dim i As Long
    Dim r As Range
    Dim wsCheck As Worksheet

i = 0
Set wsCheck = Worksheets("JIS")
For Each r In Intersect(wsCheck.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(Col_Western), wsCheck.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)).Cells
    If wsCheck.Cells(r.Row, Col_Starter) = "S" And wsCheck.Cells(r.Row, Col_Dessert) = "WESTERN" Then
        i = i + 1
        wsCheck.Range("A5") = "S:" & " " & i
    End If
Next r


Set wsCheck = Nothing
```

Comment: Why do you need VBA for this?

Comment: @Tom, its part of larger automation program I am designing for my company. The purpose is to print out individuals classes order and also because its easier if i can run it once and use it multiple times without having to write formula each time

Answer (score 0):

Use the `hidden` property to check whether a row is filtered or not.

```
If wsCheck.Cells(r.Row, Col_Starter) = "S" And wsCheck.Cells(r.Row, Col_Dessert) = "WESTERN" And r.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
```

Comment: thanks you for your suggestion. However, it shows a compile error

Comment: @nikhilsharma Try replacing `r.Row.EntireRow.Hidden = False` with `r.EntireRow.Hidden = False`

Comment: Sorry about that. I adjusted the code. Thanks @Brotato!

Comment: Thanks @Brotato  I tried it, but the value of Range A5 doesnt change when i filter the results. Do you think its better if i use a worksheet function?

Comment: @nikhilsharma to change the value you have to have the `.Value` appended to the range